# Count of (x,y) pairs that satisfy the equation x^2+y^2 = n^2

Tags: java

Given (n) , what is the Count of (x,y) pairs that satisfy the equation x^2+y^2 = n^2. 
Is there any way I can re-write this code just without using nested loop?

```
int counter=0;
    int x=0;


    for (int i =(int) n-1; i>=0 ; i--){

        if(i == x)
            break;


        for (int j = 1; j< (int)n ; j++){

            if (Math.pow(i,2)+Math.pow(j,2) == Math.pow(n,2)){
                counter++;
                x = j;
            }
        }
    } 
System.out.print(counter);
```

Comment: This question looks like off-topic. Any way, it fits [SO] probably more.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is to try every possible $x$ and $y$ and see if $x^2+y^2=n^2$. However, $n$ is fixed and, for any $x$, either $n^2-x^2$ is a perfect square or it isn't. You can calculate what $y$ is, instead of looping and trying every possible value.

Actual code is off-topic but it's confusing that you're trying to solve a problem about $x$ and $y$, but you've represented those quantities in variables called `i` and `j`. And even worse that you have a variable called `x` that represents something else entirely. (In fact, I'm not sure it's even correct. You seem to be using `x` to avoid reporting, e.g., $x=3$, $y=4$ and $x=4$, $y=3$ as separate solutions for $n=5$. But they *are* separate solutions and the question, at least as you've summarized it, doesn't say that they should be counted as the same.)

Comment: I'm new at java and I apologize for the inconvenience, I agree with about getting x , but I don't know how I should write it as a code.